# Can we or could we?

Tags: modal-verbs

A native speaker told me that using "could" would be unnatural in the first example, but it works in the second. Do both sentences express permission?

If I am not mistaken "could" is used when asking for permission. If both express permission, then why doesn't "could" work in the first example?
Or is the first sentence asking "are we allowed?" In which case "could" isn't used?

1. Can we look words up in a dictionary?
2. Can/could I borrow your dictionary, please?

Comment: I can't see why *could* wouldn't be used in 1 if asking for permission.

Comment: (1) could be asking about ability (is there a dictionary available?) or permission.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Oh, so it's not wrong to use "could" to talk about permission? The original question was: "Can "could" be used here: "Could we look words up in a dictionary?" The answer: 
"No: "could" doesn't mean "Are we allowed to?": it means "Would we be able to?"   Perhaps it the difference between BrE and AmE?

Comment: Would it be unnatural to use "please" in the original sentence? And when talking about favors, permission, polite requests, or when asking for information?

Comment: *Could* doesn't just mean *would we be able to?*, it can also mean *please let me*. *Could we look up words...* can be a request for eg. the teacher to let you use the dictionary. But that's different from asking the teacher *if* it is allowed (ie. you're asking what the rules are, rather than pleading), in which case you'd use *can*.

Comment: @Kate Bunting if I want this sentence 1."Can we look words up in a dictionary?"  to mean "is it allowed to use?" or "am I allowed to use a dictionary?" would it be wrong to use "could"?

Comment: _Could_ can be used to politely ask permission - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/could

Comment: "Could" is possible in 1. provided the sentence is intended to refer to past time. But if it's intended to refer to present time both "can" and "could" are possible. "Can" and "could" are both possible in 2. The choice depends on whether the speaker uses dialect A or dialect B.

Comment: @Kate Bunting do you mean yes, I can use "could" if I want my sentence to mean  "is it allowed to use?", "am I allowed to use?"  because "could" can be used to politely ask permission and  its meaning is the same  as asking "am I allowed to" in this meaning? "Could=am I allowed to look words up in a dictionary?"

Comment: Dialect A is the older dialect, where "could" tends to be used for conveying past time meaning only. Dialect B is the newer one, typically spoken by 'younger' speakers, where "can" and "could" are both acceptable for present time.

Comment: Yes - 'asking permission' is asking if you are allowed to do something!

Comment: @BillJ, that's why that  native speaker  told me  "could" can't be used in the first sentence. He must be the speaker of the older dialect. Right?

Comment: Yes, the older speaker using Dialect A would use only "could" in first sentence if it referred to past time. Both "can" and "could" are used to convey present time in dialect B.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, then I don't understand Maciej Stachowski's point: "But that's different from asking the teacher if it is allowed (ie. you're asking what the rules are, rather than pleading), in which case you'd use can. – 
Maciej Stachowski." Both are used not just "can". Am I right?

Comment: Just wanted to say that ultimately this is probably why one is encouraged to use “may” in place of “could”.

Comment: It isn't a hard and fast rule, but, yes, you would probably use _can_ if you were asking about a set of rules rather than requesting permission from an individual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do both sentences express permission?

Not necessarily. Context will provide the answer. The second sentence is clearly a request for permission, but the first could be asking about what one is able to do. Say, if the previous question was "What is a dictionary for?"

But there's a third word often used for permission: *may*. *Can* technically and officially means "able to, but it is very often used in casual speech when we mean to talk about permission. Elementary school teachers and overly pedantic people might enjoy correcting it:

> "Can I ask a question?"
> "You mean *may* I ask a question. Obviously you *can*—you are able to—because you just asked one."

But such use is so widespread that the correction is perhaps unreasonable in all but the most formal contexts.

*Could* complicates things: it's just *can*, but in the conditional tense. But this conditional is commonly used to make a request less direct and more polite. "Can I/Could I borrow your dictionary?" Both are very common usage. Both will be understood (by any reasonable person) as a request for permission. But the "could" version is just a little softer (since the conditional suggests some uncertainty, some openness to the possibility that the person might say "no").

In the Disney movie *Frozen*, a bit of wordplay highlights the way *could* can shift from a hypothetical conditional to permission (and its relationship to *may*): Surprised by a gift, a character exclaims "I could kiss you!" and then, embarrassed, continues, "I could. I mean, I’d like to. May I? I mean, may we?" *Could* started simply as expressing conditional possibility, and as he shifted his meaning to requesting permission, he transitioned to *may*.

Comment: Is adding "please" unnecessary to the original sentence? And when talking about favors, permission, polite requests, or when asking for information is it better to use "please?"

Comment: "Please" is grammatically unnecessary, but always a good idea for politeness. Also, adding it to "Can we look up words in a dictionary" makes it clear that you're asking for permission, not whether you're able to.

Comment: you said  "but the first could be asking about what one is able to do. Say, if the previous question was "What is a dictionary for?" Do you mean 1."Can we look words up in a dictionary?" the first sentence means "we are able to use it to find new words?"

Comment: @AntoniaA Yes, that could be a meaning if the context led to that understanding. Or it could also be a request if the context (or adding "please," or changing "can" to "could") made the request clear.

Comment: thank you! when talking about polite requests favours, etc,  in "could you help me, please?" and "can you help me, please?" Is "please" also grammatically unnecessary in such sentences?

Comment: You mentioned *permission* and *request* when you said: "Also, adding it to "Can we look up words in a dictionary" makes it clear that you're asking for permission, not whether you're able to"  and "Or it could also be a request if the context (or adding "please," or changing "can" to "could") made the request clear." Do you mean a request and permission mean the same or are they different things in English?

Comment: @AntoniaA 1) Let's not use a comment section for new questions; questions about "please" should be posted separately. (But the grammar doesn't have to do with the word "please," but about dependent clauses, which can be removed from a sentence without making the sentence ungrammatical.) 2) "Request" and "permission" are not synonyms, but I was using them to talk about the same thing, "a request for permission." I suppose you could also use can/could for a request that someone *do* something: "Could you pass me the salt?" (But you *couldn't* use "may" in this situation!)

Comment: Thank you. I will post a new question.